# ASPX file in disguise of an HTM ? - (cURL related)

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to cURL a site, but can't get the results I am after, although I seem to do what it takes (or at least I thought so)

The traffic shows some files named `htm,css,js` and of course one or two `aspx` files.

My assumption was that all javascript, html, css files are meaningless to the result, but after quite a few unsuccessful tries, it came to my mind that maybe these files are `aspx` files in disguise and I actually need to access these files as well...

Is it possible to have an `aspx` file and make all the clients think it is an `htm` file ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite it to just about anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking of just "changing the filetype" for the clients, have a look at mod_rewrite for apache. Here is an example on how to let all .php files be accessed as .html files:

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=5801

So this here should work for you (According to the post. I haven't tried it):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html$ /$1.aspx [QSA,L]
```

Be aware of that you won't be able to access .html files that are named like .aspx files in the same directroy. In this case the .aspx will take priority.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I learnt that you can completely omit the filename so that your file could be accessed as: http://site.com/login/ for example. Good to know!